# KDB Select from partitioned table where date is less than a given date - 1 day

Tags: database, date, select, where-clause, kdb

I would like to select from a partitioned table where the date is the highest date strictly below a given date `d`.

I can do the following:

```
d:2019.10.02;
{select from x where date = max date} select from t where date < d
```

where `t` is my partitioned table.

The issue with the above query is that it is very slow as it has to first load all the dates strictly older than `d`, and then taking the `max date` out of it.

Comment: To clarify, is the table _splayed_ (i.e. one directory for *all* dates containing file for each column) or _partitioned_ (i.e. one directory for *each* date, each containing files for each column)?

Comment: Sorry, it is partitioned (there is one directory per date). Of course I would like to avoid doing something like system "ls -l" on the folder to list all the dates, and take the one I want...

Comment: `get .Q.pf` will list all partition fields for a partitioned database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to select from the max date in a date partitioned hdb

Lets assume that the max populated date partition less than 2019.08.20 is 2019.08.07

```
q)d:2019.08.20
q)select from t where date=max date where date<d
```

This is because the partition type is available as a variable once you load into a DB, (i.e,. date, month, int etc). This will be the `.Q.pf` variable.

Comment: Sorry, this is not exactly what I intend to do. I have edited the question.

Comment: If it's petitioned to one directory per date and then splayed tables within reach date directory then you won't need to use ls, the variable will exist as `date`

Answer (score 3):

To select all the dates that are earlier than your specified date you can use the select statement below:

`select from t where date=max date where date<d`

Where `t` is your partitioned table and `d` is your specified date.

Answer (score 1):

```
select from table where date=(last .Q.pv where .Q.pv < d)
```

Answer (score 0):

kdb+ stores a variable in memory which contains all the dates within your db.

`select from telemetry where date=desc[date]1`

Above where clause will sort this by largest ->smallest

Selecting index 1 will filter the max date out of your query (without first querying the entire dataset).

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question as I actually want to take the max date out of the table where the date is below a given date, not below the max date... Apologizes